# Pointer declarations in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, pointers

When reading various texts or code examples on Obj-C I see pointer declarations like this:

```
NSString *myStringPtr
```

but sometimes I see,

```
NSString * myStringPtr
```

where there is a space between the name and the *.

Is there a difference between these declarations or are they both just pointers to an object of type NSString or am I missing something?

In general is the space between the * and name necessary?

I have even seen
    NSString* myStringPtr

Is this any different than the above statements?

I realize (NSString *) for method return types or arguments means the method is returning (or being passed) a pointer to an NSString object.

Answer (score 1):

No, the asterisk can be attached to either the name or the type, or in between (with spaces as padding). It makes no difference. However, Objective-C most commonly uses the style

```
NSString *myStr;
```

rather than

```
NSString * myStr;
```

or

```
NSString* myStr;
```

The placement of the pointer *does* make a difference if you declare multiple variables one one line. For example, this

```
int* a, b;
```

is functionally identical to this:

```
int *a;
int  b;    /* Note: This is not a pointer! */
```

<sup>(Note: This also applies to C, as this is technically a C syntax issue and not specific to Objective-C.)</sup>